# How enable ModelState validation just for one Model in ASP.Net Core Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am using ASP.Net Core Razor Pages web application. I have two Models in my code behind and want to enable ModelState validation just for one of them. Now, when I click on the submit button, it validates both of them.

My Modls:

```
public class Model1
    {
        [Key]
        public int Model1Id{ get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Model1Name")]
        [Required]
        public string Model1Name{ get; set; }
    }



public class Model2
    {
        [Key]
        public int Model2Id{ get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Model2Name")]
        [Required]
        public string Model2Name{ get; set; }
    }
```

in cshtml.cs file:

```
    [BindProperty]
    public Model1 Model1{ get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public Model2 Model2{ get; set; }
```

I am using the following code in the OnPost Method but it validates both of them, but I want to validate just Model1 for example:

```
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
            
           //Do something.
     }
   else
     {
           //Do something else
     }
```

Is there any way?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ModelState.Remove()` and View Model

```
  //create a ViewModel contaions Model1 and Model2
  public class Model3
    {
        public Model1 M1 { get; set; }
        public Model2 M2 { get; set; }

    }
```

**PageModel**

```
 //.......
 public Model3 model {get; set; }

 public void OnPost()
{
    //if you don't want to validate Model1,
    //you can remove the key of Model1 in ModelState.Remove()

    ModelState.Remove("model.M1.Model1Id");
    ModelState.Remove("model.M1.Model1Name");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Do something.
    }
    else 
    { 
         //Do something else
    }
}
```

**You can see ModelState just validate the attributes in Model2**

[image]

Comment: This feels a bit of a 'hacked solution', but it does the trick.